# Get the index of NaN values from a selected set of rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like this,

```
    ID   Cus_ID cl_id
0   5.0  200    0
1   NaN  200    0
2   NaN  200    1
3   14.0 200    2
4   15.0 200    2
5   16.0 200    2
6   NaN  200    3
```

From dataframe above, I am want to extract rows 0 through 4 and check if there is any values in 'ID' column has a `NaN` values. I tried this,

```
rows_needed = [0,1,2,3,4]

df.iloc[rows_needed,0].isnull().index.tolist()
```

But I get the following,

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I am expecting to get the indexes of `[1,2]`. How can I get my desired output?

When I do this,

```
df.iloc[rows_needed,0].isnull()
```

I get,

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

Not sure where I am making the mistake not to get my output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very very close, what you need to do is chain `.iloc` and `.loc` with a `==TRUE` to get your result

```
your_indices = (df.iloc[rows_needed]
                .loc[df.ID.isnull()==True]
                .index.tolist())

print(your_indices)
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

Two steps for clarity. Slice, then mask based on that slice.

---

```
u = df.iloc[rows_needed, 0]

u[u.isnull()].index.tolist()
```

```
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us chain it `loc` will only pick the result yield True out

```
rows_needed = [0,1,2,3,4]
df.iloc[rows_needed,0].isnull().loc[lambda x : x].index.tolist()
Out[240]: [1, 2]
```

Comment: I beat you to it for once : ), nice one with the lambda I wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: @Datanovice ah :-) .loc is a small trick for chain this type functions :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `index.symmetric_different` with `dropna` to find those index is not `NaN` as follows:

```
df.iloc[rows_needed,0].dropna().index.symmetric_difference(rows_needed).tolist()
```

or

```
(df.iloc[rows_needed,0].dropna().index ^ rows_needed).tolist()

Out[684]: [1, 2]
```